# Logout issues with validators on the page. ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a website that I log into. In my pages that are viewable while logged in, there is a logout button that logs the user out and takes the user back to the login page. The problem is on certain pages, I have textboxes that have requiredFieldValidators. Now when I hit the logout button, the requiredFieldValidators for the textboxes pop up and won't let me log out.

What do I need to change?

```
protected void btLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Contents.RemoveAll();
    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following on your log-out button declaration:

```
CausesValidation="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `ValidationGroup` property for the validators and controls you want to validate and make sure that the Log Out button is not part of the group.